# Installing qt4-mac Using Macports on El Capitan | Installing ports via MacPorts

Tags: macos, qt4, macports

I am currently trying to install qt4-mac for the purposes of installing edfbrowser on my mac.

I am running:

- OS X El Capitan (10.11.5)
- XCode (7.3.1)
- Macports 2.3.4 installed using https://www.macports.org/install.php with the package installer

However, when I run the following command

```
sudo port install qt4-mac
Password:
Error: Port qt4-mac not found
```

I am not sure how to debug this, or even how to go about checking what is wrong because no one else online seemed to have this issue (after many google searches).
I was wondering if anyone knew the right direction to go in and could offer their help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to do `port selfupdate` and then try to install again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sudo port selfupdate` first to fetch the available ports.

Additionally, you might want to try the qt5 port instead as Qt5 is the latest release of Qt.